# Coding a shell - Is the clion-Terminal the same as the default linux-shell

Tags: c++, linux, shell

Introduction (not that important): I have to write a simple linux shell in c++ for my course in university and I'm confused how to test my code. Pressing <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to run the compile statement `g++ file.cpp` and next in another terminal window <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to run the execution statement `./a.out` again and again is really annoying. So I'm looking for a proper (faster) solution.

**Question**: Is the terminal, which is shipped in JetBrain's "clion"-IDE, the same as that one my mint-machine is running? If there are differences, please let me know how to write this code in a efficient way.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `alias r='g++ file.cpp && ./a.out'`?

Comment: @molbdnilo that's a nice advice. Thanks :)

Comment: Not good enough. Try `rm -f main && g++ file.cpp -o main && ./main`. But then again, you could just write a simple `Makefile`.